# If $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $K$ and $K\subseteq L \subseteq \Sigma$, show that $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $L$.

Tags: field-theory, proof-writing

If $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $K$ and $K\subseteq L \subseteq \Sigma$, show that $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $L$.

I believe the general idea of this proof is as follows...

If $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $K$ , then all the roots of $f$ are in $\Sigma$. Since $K\subseteq L \subseteq \Sigma$, then all the roots of $f$ are in $L$, which implies that $\Sigma$ is the splitting field for $f$ over $L$.

Is there a more formal way to describe what I stated?

Comment: Oops, by definition, the roots of $f$ are in $\Sigma$, not $K$ as you write. Firstly, what is your definition of splitting field of a polynomial?

Comment: a splitting field of a polynomial with coefficients in a field is a smallest field extension of that field over which the polynomial splits or decomposes into linear factors.

Comment: Something like it will work, with correction of major typos. Certainly $f$ considered as a polynomial over $L$ splits in $\Sigma$. Argue that no intermediate field between $L$ and $\Sigma$ will work.

Comment: How would I argue that part?

Comment: If some such field $M$ were a splitting field for $f$ over $L$, then $f$ considered as a polynomial over $K$ would split over $M$, contradicting the fact that $\Sigma$ is a splitting field for $f$ over $K$.